# Matplotlib animation erase previous data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a simple animation with Matplotlib to check that my simulation runs well. I want to see how two particles move in the x-y plane: if the code works, they should attract and end in the same point or close in space.

I compute the positions of the particles inside a 'for' loop and each time I get the positions, I plot them using plt.scatter(x, y), where x and y are the positions at time t = t + dt. I have read online that I can write plt.pause(0.05) inside the loop and this will produce the simple animation I am looking for.

An example of my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for k in range(steps):
    pos = computeNewPos(pos, vel, force)        

    plt.scatter(pos[0, 0], pos[0, 1], label = '1', color = 'r')
    plt.scatter(pos[1, 0], pos[1, 1], label = '2', color = 'b')

    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')

    plt.pause(0.05)

plt.show()
```

This works, but the 'animation' I get contains old data points and I would like to only see the updated position. This will make it easier to keep track of where the particles are. How can I 'erase' the old points for each run inside the for loop? Is there a way of clearing the frame at each run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution (if perhaps not the most efficient) is to wipe the axis with `axis.clear()` before redrawing:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k in range(steps):
    pos = computeNewPos(pos, vel, force)
    ax.clear()        

    ax.scatter(pos[0, 0], pos[0, 1], label = '1', color = 'r')
    ax.scatter(pos[1, 0], pos[1, 1], label = '2', color = 'b')

    ax.xlabel('X')
    ax.ylabel('Y')

    plt.pause(0.05)

plt.show()
```

Note that I'm generating the figure and axis in the beginning (so it still work with multiple windows open). You could also use `plt.gca().clear()` to clear the current axis, but that's IMO more brittle and prone to error.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: This option (axis.clear()) resets my xtick rotation settings